# mysql connection on remote virtual machine in spring boot

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot, database-connection, virtual-machine

I have created a project in Spring boot and JPA which is deployed on a VM and my database is on another VM. At time of deployment it is taking to much time to connect to the database and also for every request(read/write operation) also it is taking more time then normal (when mysql was on the same VM).

My application.properties file is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<remoteip>:3306/dbname?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password =root
// Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

And gradle file

```
compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:1.5.1.RELEASE")
```

Is this happening because JPA creating connection pool?
i am using undertow server.

Comment: Did you try to connect the database from spring project's VM  via bash mysql connector or some mysql visualizer? I believe your queries will be slow same as project's connection. If not then it can be spring-boot related issue. Otherwise it network issue between VMs

Comment: database connection is managed by Spring boot

Comment: Hi, I know db connection is managed by spring boot. I am suggesting that, try to access database via some other viewer program from your VM and see if the connection is still slow.

Comment: ya I connect to that database using toad its working fine

Comment: In that case may be spring can't fill connection pool with enough connection or can't take connection at all. Is db configured to limit connections or something like that. Your spring project configurations seem pretty default shouldn't make any problem.

Comment: No I haven't configured anything in database.